# How to check the type of tkinter-widget-objects

Tags: python, if-statement, tkinter, tkinter-entry

I wanna create a simple GUI for a research project.
For this I have plenty of widgets and I want to check what their type is.
Lets take the entry-widget as an example. I have entries, which look like this:

```
entry_modelling_script_folder = tk.Entry(self, width=40)
entry_modelling_script_folder.grid(row=6,column=0)
```

Now I want to check wether a certain widget is an entry:

```
widget_type = type(current_widget)
```

which returns:
*<class 'tkinter.Entry'>*

Now - how do I write the if-condition?
I only came up with stuff, that is not working:

```
if widget_type == '<class \'tkinter.Entry\'>':
if widget_type == 'tkinter.Entry':
...
```

I would really appreciate any help =)

(I know, there is a method .winfo_class() too, but this didnt work in the first step, so I chose type(...))

Comment: The type of the widget is exactly the same as the type you called to create it: `tk.Entry` in this case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `isinstance`:

```
if isinstance(current_widget, tk.Entry):
    ...
```

Or

```
if widget_type == 'tkinter.Entry':
    ...
```

I prefer the first solution.